# .NET ZipPackage vs DotNetZip when getting streams to entries

Tags: dotnetzip

I have been using the ZipPackage-class in .NET for some time and I really like the simple and intuitive API it has. When reading from an entry I do entry.GetStream() and I read from this stream. When writing/updating an entry I do entry.GetStream(FileAccess.ReadWrite) and write to this stream. Very simple and useful because I can hand over the reading/writing to some other code not knowing where the Stream comes from originally.

Now since the ZipPackage-API doesn't contain support for entry properties such as LastModified etc I have been looking into other zip-api's such as DotNetZip. But I'm a bit confused over how to use it. For instance, when wanting to read from an entry I first have to extract the entire entry into a MemoryStream, seek to the beginning and hand-over this stream to my other code. And to write to an entry I have to input a stream that the ZipEntry itself can read from. This seem very backwards to me. Am I using this API in a wrong way?

Isn't it possible for the ZipEntry to deliver the file straight from the disk where it is stored and extract it as the reader reads it? Does it really need to be fully extracted into memory first? I'm no expert but it seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I'm answering this my self because I found the answers. There are apparently methods for both these things I wanted in DotNetZip. For opening a read-stream -> myZipEntry.OpenReader() and for opening a write-stream -> myZipFile.UpdateEntry(e, (fn, obj) => Serialize(obj)). This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

using the DotNetZip libraries does not require you to read the entire zip file into a memory stream. When you instantiate an instance an instance of ZipFile as shown below, the library is only reading from the zip file header. The zip file headers contain properties such as last modified, etc. Here is an example of opening a zip file. The DotNetZip library then reads the zip file headers and constructs a list of all entries on the zip:

using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(this.FileAbsolutePath))
{
...
}

It's up to you to then extract zip files either to a stream, to the file system, etc. In the example below, I'm using a string property accessor on zipFile to get a zip file named SomeFile.txt. The matching ZipEntry object is then extracted to a memory stream.

MemoryStream memStr = new MemoryStream();
zipFile["SomeFile.txt"].Extract(memStr); // Response.OutputStream);

Zip entries must be read into the .NET process space in order to be deflated, there's no way to bypass that by going straight into the filesystem. Similar to how your Windows Explorer shell zip extractor would work - The Windows shell extensions for 7zip or Windows built in Compressed Folders have to read entries into memory and then write them to the file system in order for you to be able to open an entry.

Comment: Of what I've read about DotNetZip it seem to be able to stream-decompress directly from disk and also stream-compress back to disc without having to buffer it all in memory. But I might be mistaken... Or perhaphs it's only when turning of compression. If this is not the case I have to reconsider using DotNetZip again. I really don't need compression. I would prefer direct streaming over compression-support.